# Websocket Connection on AWS always results in TOO MANY REQUESTS even with one request

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, websocket, terraform

So I have this terraform that seems to deploy a websocket api connection to AWS BUT....
Once deployed, when I connect, I consistently get "429 too many requests" errors.
Using terraform 0.13.4.
I've turned up the requests manually in the console but every time I `wscat -c {MYENDPOINT}` I get a 429.
Can't find anything online or anything in the manuals about this.
Here is the terraform. Wondering if anyone can see if I'm missing something in my routes or integrations?
Here is the response I keep getting from the logs:
`(VH_SDESljoEF7tg=) Gateway response body:  { "message": "Too Many Requests", "connectionId": "VH_SDd21joECIeg=", "requestId": "VH_SDESljoEF7tg=" }`

and

```
(VH_SDESljoEF7tg=) Key throttle limit exceeded for RestApi k27g2ypii6, Stage test, Resource $connect, HttpMethod GET. Limit: 42.00 Burst: 0
```

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "websocket-api" {
  name                       = "websocket-api"
  protocol_type              = "WEBSOCKET"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "chatRoomConnectIntegration" {
  api_id           = aws_apigatewayv2_api.websocket-api.id
  integration_type = "AWS_PROXY"
  integration_uri  = aws_lambda_function.ChatRoomConnectFunction.invoke_arn
  integration_method = "POST"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "connectRoute" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.websocket-api.id
  route_key = "$connect"
  target = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.chatRoomConnectIntegration.id}"
}
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_deployment" "deploy" {
  api_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_api.websocket-api.id
  description = "testing deployment"

  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(join(",", list(
      jsonencode(aws_apigatewayv2_integration.chatRoomConnectIntegration),
      jsonencode(aws_apigatewayv2_route.connectRoute),
    )))
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "test-stage" {
  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api.websocket-api.id
  name   = "test"
  access_log_settings {
    destination_arn = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.access_logs.arn
    format = "$context.identity.sourceIp - - [$context.requestTime] \"$context.httpMethod $context.routeKey $context.protocol\" $context.status $context.responseLength $context.requestId $context.integrationErrorMessage"
  }
  default_route_settings {
    data_trace_enabled = true
    logging_level = "INFO"
    throttling_rate_limit = 42
  }
  route_settings {
    route_key = "$connect"
    data_trace_enabled = true
    logging_level = "INFO"
    throttling_rate_limit = 42
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_account" "api_gateway_accesslogs" {
  cloudwatch_role_arn = aws_iam_role.cloudwatch.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "cloudwatch" {
  name = "api_gateway_cloudwatch_global"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "cloudwatch" {
  name = "default"
  role = aws_iam_role.cloudwatch.id

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:GetLogEvents",
                "logs:FilterLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_api_gateway" {
  action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.ChatRoomConnectFunction.arn
  statement_id = "AllowExecutionFromApiGateway"
  principal = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.websocket-api.execution_arn}/*/*/*"
}

output "endpoint" {
  value = aws_apigatewayv2_stage.test-stage.invoke_url
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find the reason for this? I'm getting the same.

Answer (score 5):

I can't explain the cause of the throttling, but I added this block to my `aws_apigatewayv2_stage` resource, triggered a new deployment, and now I'm able to connect using `wscat`:

```
  default_route_settings {
    throttling_rate_limit = 100
    throttling_burst_limit = 50
  }
```

([relevant docs here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_stage#throttling_burst_limit))

Comment: This is it! Terraform uses 0 by default and it seems to be interpreted differently for HTTP APIs (use default limits) than it is for Websocket APIs (fix the limit at 0).

Comment: That helped me as well. I was using Terraform and the defaults were indeed `0`, like @Krotton reported. Thank you :)